# Chmod a file using php

Tags: php, chmod

Let's say i allow the user to upload a file to my website.

Using php, i am giving this an address,

```
$pic = '/~start/B7/images/456.jpg'
```

how can i chmod this file to make it readable using php?
I have tried `chmod ($pic, 0705);` but that doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If PHP would need write permissions to change permissions.  Write without read permissions is very rare.  Is this the case?  (e.g., 0222 or 0333.)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand i gave the images folder 777 permissions to test, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I would suspect the issue is that your path in $pic is an absolute URL, but that doesn't correlate to the absolute file system path. Does adding something like dirname(__FILE__) to your $pic declaration, and then pointing to the image relative to the script you're running, help?

Comment: That file path looks suspicious.  What is the folder "~start"?  If you meant for a relative path, remove the leading `/`, which makes it absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` function will allow you execute shell commands. Try this:

```
<?php
 exec("chmod $pic 0705");
?>
```

Comment: the file is actually saved on a file server, in a folder called images which is in public_html, the php script is also in public_html. This still doesn't work. i tried changing $pic to images/456.jpg as well, which didn't work.

Comment: i did chmod 705 images/456.jpg from the command line, which does work.. while in the public_html directory

Comment: try `exec("ls", $outs); echo var_dump($outs);`  What's the output?  Is your images folder in the output?

Comment: By the way, giving images execution privs is always a bad idea.  666 will work as well as 777 for testing purposes.